# Intersection of Ker of two linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $T,S: \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ be two linear maps with:
> \begin{equation} T(e_1)=1,T(e_2)=0,  S(e_1)=0, S(e_2)=1.\end{equation}
> I have to compute $\dim(\ker T \cap \ker S)$.

Let $v \in \ker T \cap \ker S$ with $v=a_1e_1+...+a_ne_n$. So if $v \in \ker T$ we have $a_1T(e_1)+a_2T(e_2)+...+a_nT(e_n)=0$ and if $v \in \ker S$ we have $a_1S(e_1)+a_2S(e_2)+...+a_nS(e_n)=0$. So $a_1+a_3T(e_3)+...+a_nT(e_n)=0$ and $a_2+a_3S(e_3)+...+a_nS(e_n)=0.$ How could I conclude?

Comment: We don't know what, say, $T(e_3)$ is, or $S(e_3)$. Is it both zero? Then the intersection of the kernels also contains $e_3$.

Comment: $n=2$? ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @azif00 Why then the whole effort with a long sum $a_1S(e_1)+a_2S(e_2)+\cdots +a_nS(e_n)$ if just $n=2$?

Comment: No, n is a integer $\geq 2$. And I don't know anything about $T(e_3),S(e_3)$.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps consider the map $A:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $Ax = (Tx, Sx)$. Then $x \in \ker A$ **iff** $s \in \ker T \cap \ker S$.

Then we have $n = \dim {\cal R A} + \dim \ker A = 2 +  \dim \ker A$ and
so
$ \dim \ker A = \dim (\ker T \cap \ker S) = n-2$.